# separating numbers from letters; python

Tags: python, string

I want to separate numbers from letters. I tried it like this, but it won't work with negative numbers. What do i have to change?

```
match = re.match(r"([0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?)([a-z]+)", "-0.5m", re.I)
number = match.group(1)
letter = = match.group(2)
```

Comment: Some regexp wiz here will probably figure this out but, what's your string syntax like? can you give an example string to match against?

Comment: Can you provide a set of expected input/output couples?

Comment: there is an example in my question the string is "-0.5m" and i want -0.5 as number and m as letter, but positiv numbers should work too.

Answer (score 3):

```
match = re.match(r"(-?[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?)([a-z]+)", "-0.5m", re.I)
```

Adds `-?` to optionally allow a minus sign at the start of the number.

Comment: Note that the . in the regex should be a \. as the . can be any character.